# UIBarButtonItem working but not visible with Xcode11 and Xcode12

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

After migrating our app to Xcode12 from Xcode10 we are seing an issue with our UIBarButtonItems. Some of those are not visible but still working.

We were able to target more specifically the following:

- Xcode10.3 on iOS12: no issue
- Xcode10.3 on iOS13 through release: no issue
- Xcode10.3 on iOS14 through release: no issue
- Xcode11.7 on iOS12: no issue
- Xcode11.7 on iOS13: issue is there
- Xcode12.0.1 on iOS12: no issue
- Xcode12.0.1 on iOS13: issue is there
- Xcode12.0.1 on iOS14: issue is there
- Issue appears either in Debug and in Release
- Issue does not appear when we run the app from Xcode
- Issue appears only when we quit the app and launch it again from the device directly
- Issue appears only with UIBarButtonItem being System Item with icon, such as: Refresh, Add, ...
- Issue does not appear with UIBarButtonItem being System Item with text, such as: Edit, Close, ...
- Issue does not appear with UIBarButtonItem being Custom with image from assets
- Issue appears also if I do the UIBarButtonItem System programmatically

When looking at the "hierarchy view" the item and its icon is there, but not shown on the device.
We do not see any difference when the item is shown or not that could help to understand the problem.

Below the screenshot are:

1. Storyboard
2. Issue on iPad after launch from icon
3. View hierarchy of the issue

More screenshots (comparison) are available here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKhkG.jpg

[image: Storyboard]
[image: Issue on iPad after launch from icon]
[image: View hierarchy of the issue]

Any chance someone has seen a similar behavior with Xcode11 or Xcode12?
Any idea of what we could try or if it is an Xcode issue that needs to be reported for a fix?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you could check if systems symbol image "arrow.clockwise" is available when implemented as plain UIImage in a normal UIView in all deployment target versions. When the icon does not appear when starting up on device directly you could also check your initWithCoder functions for proper initiation. Some of the symbols have been deprecated and won't appear at all cause they are not existent, so a fallback mechanism like from a costume image asset would solve it.

Comment: Hello @OlSen, I've tried with an `UIImageView` with system image `arrow.clockwise` and this image [works fine](https://i.imgur.com/TiTxMsX.png) even when I relaunch the app. The `UIViewController` here isn't a custom one here, but I tried with a simple one just to verify the flow with logs. Wether I launch with Xcode or icon it's correct: initWithCoder > viewDidLoad > viewWillAppear > viewWillLayoutSubviews > viewDidLayoutSubviews > viewDidAppear.

Comment: then i would try to exchange the icon sorting and watch if the right most icon disappears or not. That way you know it would be clearly a layout issue. Then possibly because the frame width is unknown when the View of the ViewController is loading. You can watch this by multiple `NSLog(@"width = %f", frame.width)` in all layout methods.. you will find some methods that don't have a width the moment they are called..

Comment: Already tried, no matter what the position are, the items with system icons doesn't appear... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were not able to reproduce in another application from scratch.
Therefore we add to proceed the other way around: strip our current application until the problem wasn't here anymore.
First step was to tear down to only an AppDelegate and a simple piece of code but the problem was still here.
We removed all the dependencies from cocoapods but the problem was still here.
We eventually removed a framework that we added directly into the project and it was the culprit!

The said framework is `BiometricSDK` (from IDEMIA). We will send them a mail to know if they are aware of this issue and if they have fixed / will fix it in a newer release. It isn't open-source so I don't know what the specific issue was, my only guess it's that they somehow changed appearance of UIBarButtonItems (yet I'm not sure how their code invoked since we had removed any reference to it while stripping down the application).

Answer (score 0):

System Font Symbols have been changed since their introduction, so they can be referred as SF Symbols 1 and SF Symbols 2, where SF Symbols 1 are part of SF Symbols 2 (which support multicolor symbols) and some have also been changed in detail.

Some symbols (actually a lot of them) have been available even before iOS 13 but in general the Docs say...

> SF Symbols are available in iOS 13 and later, macOS 11 and later, watchOS 6 and later, and tvOS 13 and later.

So the specific symbol `arrow.clockwise` you try to use is part of the SF Symbol 1 Collection and is one of those who have been available even before iOS 13 as `Refresh` Symbol. But as they are re-introduced as SF Symbols you run into trouble here. In targets below iOS 13 they (some) appear as part of UIKit's Controls and above iOS 12 they are System Font Symbols that respect multiple parameters of your UI, like darkMode, lightMode, anyMode, FontWeight, localization and so on.

From Apple Documentation.. [Creating Custom Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/)

> If you need a symbol that isn't provided by SF Symbols, you can create your own. The SF Symbols app lets you export a symbol as a **template** in a reusable, vector-based file format.

and also

> When you export a symbol introduced in SF Symbols 2 as an **SVG template** and bundle it with your app, you can use it in apps that target iOS 13, Mac Catalyst 13, tvOS 13, or watchOS 6, but without the benefit of SF Symbol 2 features like multicolor support and automatic localization.

The mentioned SF Symbols Tools to **export and verify** SVG format SF symbols can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/).
 See how SF Symbols 1.1 app that
requires macOS 10.14.4 or later looks like.

[image: Screenshot SF Symbols 1.1 app]

The arrow.clockwise symbol is not marked with `(i)` which would tell you about copyrights and other informations that you would have to respect.

The exported SVG file contains all weighted symbols and layout guides to keep up this SF Symbol features and will help you develop graphics with it. The Format is explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app?language=objc)

This SVG file can't be dropped as is into your Apps Assets unless you are targeting OSX 10.15 or iOS 13. The compiler will warn you if you try to do this below the mentioned versions. But you can open it in Sketch or similar to edit the SVG data and generate a graphic as workaround. Which i would suggest to do so and load this graphics into your UI Element instead.

The use of System Font Symbols starting iOS 13 and how to load them is explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/configuring_and_displaying_symbol_images_in_your_ui?language=objc#3234560)

and as you did set your `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically in code it could also be written like..

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = nil;
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    UITraitCollection *trait = [UITraitCollection currentTraitCollection];
    barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"arrow.clockwise" compatibleWithTraitCollection:trait] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshMethodHere)];
} else {
    barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshMethodHere)];
}
```

Comment: if you set the UIBarButtonItem's content programmatically please present your code, because pretty sure it can be solved with two lines of code targeting iOS 13.

Comment: I'm targeting iOS12 minimum on our project/targets. Sadly I'm not looking for just a workaround. I know that if I use custom images from assets it works properly. But it's not a solution to manually replace every System Item/Icon from both Interface Builder and sometimes from code  `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshMethodHere)];`. Especially it's not just "Refresh" but also "Add", "Trash" and other icons. _TSI is now open at Apple Developer, will post if something is found._

Comment: updated my answer so you have at least a workaround that depends on your target versions. What is actually annoying is that UIBarButtonSystemItems are not marked deprecated while their symbols are now SF Symbols reacting to UITraitCollection

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur when you set title text attribute `foregroundColor` of the `UIBarButtonItem` to `UIColor.clear`.

You could do this directly, eg.:

```swift
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

or by modifying the appearance of the `UIBarButtonItem`, eg:

```swift
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
```

Check your code, maybe you have such setting somewhere.